# How to use HtmlTextWritter in MVC6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am a beginner in mvc. When I upgrade my project into MVC6, I have face some problems and also unable to find the solution. My code block is :

```
public static void WriteTo(HtmlHelper helper, string value)
    {
        var baseWriter = helper.ViewContext.Writer;
        using (HtmlTextWriter textWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(baseWriter))
        {
            textWriter.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Type, "text/javascript");
            textWriter.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Script);
            textWriter.Write(value);
            textWriter.RenderEndTag();
        }
    }
```

If there is any way to achieve the same scenario(like use of the HtmlTextWritter) in MVC6 or if there is any mistake in my code block.can you please suggest the solution. Even tried with google, but I can't get the opt solution.

Comment: @thanks CodeCaster: Any alternative way to achieve this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

The MVC equivalent of that archaic format (HtmlTextWriter is for WebForms) is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">@value</script>
```

Where `value` is a variable that is present in your view.

Comment: the "value" have passed from another one method "WriteTo(helper, string.Format(content));" In this method only i already did the htmltextwriter operation,.